# Function not processing every step

Tags: powershell

The below snippet will jump to the correct function "ORD_LOG_PROCESS", it will CD to the path, but it will not store the variables after that.  $ordfiles and every variable after that do not store.  There is one file in the $ordlogpath directory, and if I do (gci $ordlogpath |% {$_.name}) at the shell it works, but via the script for some reason it will not store.

```
$ordlogpath = "C:\test_environment\ORD_REPO\ORD_LOGS\"
$ordlogexist = gci "C:\test_environment\ORD_REPO\ORD_LOGS\*.log"


FUNCTION ORD_LOG_PROCESS
{
cd $ordlogpath
$ordfiles = (gci $ordlogpath |% {$_.name})
FOREACH ($ordfile in $ordfiles)
{
$ordlogimport = Import-Csv $ordfile
$ordloggrep = $ordfile
exit
}
}

FUNCTION NO_FILES

{
write-host "NO FILES TO PROCESS"
EXIT
}

IF (!$ordlogexist)

{
NO_FILES
}

else

{
ORD_LOG_PROCESS
}
```

Comment: What value does `$ordfiles` hold in the script when ran?

Comment: Your `FUNCTION ORD_LOG_PROCESS` (why do you write all caps?) doesn't return anything, it just overwrites two variables on every iteration. BTW your formatting is suboptimal...

Comment: I've cleared the variable several times, it doesn't hold anything when the script starts, if I run that exact same command from the cli it returns the log name

Comment: @LotPings, i've always written functions in all caps for some reason, and it's clearly not done, i'm just wondering why that variable comes up empty every run

Comment: Read `Get-help about_scopes` or [online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-5.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare variables inside a function, they will be local to that function. That means that the variables do not exist outside the function.

But then.. why use functions like this at all?
Can't you simply do something like below?

```
$ordlogpath  = "C:\test_environment\ORD_REPO\ORD_LOGS\*.log"

if (!(Test-Path -Path $ordlogpath)) {
    Write-Host "NO FILES TO PROCESS"
}
else {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $ordlogpath -File | ForEach-Object {
        $ordlogimport = Import-Csv $_.FullName
        # now do something with the $ordlogimport object, 
        # otherwise you are simply overwriting it with the next file that gets imported..
        # perhaps store it in an array?

        # it is totally unclear to me what you intend to do with this variable..
        $ordloggrep = $_.Name
    }

    Write-Host "The log name is: $ordloggrep"
    Write-Host
    Write-Host 'The imported variable ordlogimport contains:'
    Write-Host

    $ordlogimport | Format-Table -AutoSize

}
```

Comment: The Function is because it's all going to snap into a larger script when it's done.  This part is supposed to move files based on strings in the "file" columns of the .csv,

Comment: @200mg You never mentioned any .CSV or did I overlook that? Anyway, if you really feel you need to use functions, have a look at [about_scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6]). Declare the variables you want available in the functions of your script by declaring them as  `$script:ordlogimport` or even `$global:ordlogimport`

Comment: It's all good, this got me over the hump i was on, like @LotPings pointed out, it's just not knowing enough about Functions, thank you for all your help, i'm always amazed when I get on stack, you guys can do what I do in 10 lines in 5 lines...=)